# How to get all the controls inside iframe ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe

I need find all controls inside iframe

for e.g below method finds all controls inside .aspx page

```
private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, List<T>  resultCollection)
where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        //if (control.GetType() == typeof(T))
        if (control is T) // This is cleaner
            resultCollection.Add((T)control);

        if (control.HasControls())
            GetControlList(control.Controls, resultCollection);
    }
}
```

like above method i need for iframe ....
So i tried below java script

```
function find() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
    var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? 
                 iframe.contentDocument : 
                 iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var dd = innerDoc.getElementById('label1').innerHTML;
}
```

But i need to pass control id ...

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to read .aspx page in string builder then use Regex To find id and text of the control